# A resources-efficient way to compare views to layouts in Android

Tags: java, android, view

I need to check if a certain View has been initialized with a certain layout. 
What I've done now to solve it is:

```
if( mView == inflater.inflate( R.layout.main_item, null ) )
```

Is there a more efficient way to implement this kind of comparison ?

Comment: you can check if the view is not null

Comment: well that's not good enough, because then if it was initialized with other layout it would still enter the if statement. 
In my case, I want it to enter the if statement only if it has been initialized with this specific layout.

Comment: I don't believe your `if` conditional is ever going to be true. One option is to set the tag on `mView` to the layout's ID when you initialize it, then check that in the `if`.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( mView == inflater.inflate( R.layout.main_item, null ) )
```

is gonna be always false. Either because `mView` is or is not null. That's because `inflater.inflate` returns a new instance of `main_item.xml` every time it is invoked. You could check the view with `getId()`, if you assigned one to the root in `main_item.xml`

Answer (score 0):

For my future self, by example:

```
int itemId = view.getId();
int resID =  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, null ).getId();
if (itemId == resID )return true;
```

if view is kind of resouce then return true